# Inserting a hyperlink in an ArcGIS Pro layout

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, hyperlink, insert

Is there a way to insert one or more hyperlinks in an ArcGIS Pro layout? There does not seem to be a clear option to add a hyperlink in the "Insert" tab in the Layout viewer, nor does it work by adding an URL in a text box.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to add a hyperlink, so when you export to say, PDF, the link is clickable?

This open [idea seems to indicate that this is NOT possible](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/export-pdf-maps-with-hyperlinks-active/idi-p/947386) at this time. However, there are some indicating that using `<url> </url>` in a text element may work. (It didn't work for me)

A brief test: if I make a new text element, add what looks like a link, and export the PDF, it is indeed clickable.
Eg. **Https://www.google.com**
However, you'd need to manually style it to make it *look like a link*, by underlining it and changing it's color.

Comment: The link is indeed clickable after exporting it to PDF. Related to this, I wonder if it is possible to manually style a part of the text box (e.g. underlining it and making it blue) while leaving the remainder of that same text box unchanged (e.g. not underlined and black).

Answer (score 0):

@Foeke: You can style parts of a text box as a link like this: "<  UND  > < CLR Blue = "255" >" Put your link here "< /CLR > < /UND >"

The rest of the text should remain the same. Find "text formatting tags" for more details